# Equations of motion for coupled harmonic oscillators

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, harmonic-oscillator, coupled-oscillators

We just started QFT, and I'm following our professor's notes but there is a passage I do not understand. We are speaking about a system of $N$ coupled harmonic oscillators $y_j(t)$ for $j = 1, ..., N$ and we assume our lattice periodic: $j = j+ N$. The Lagrangian reads

$$L = \frac{m}{2}\sum_j \left(\dot{y_j}^2 -v^2\left(\frac{y_j - y_{j+1}}{\Delta}\right)^2\right)$$

Where $\Delta$ is the distance between atoms among $x$.

Now by Euler-Lagrange equations $$\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{y_j}} = \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial y_j}$$ I was able to get

$$\sum_j \ddot{y_j} = \left(-\frac{v^2}{\Delta^2}\right)\sum_j (y_j - y_{j+1}).$$

hence

$$\ddot{y_j} =  \left(-\frac{v^2}{\Delta^2}\right)(y_j - y_{j+1}).$$

But my professor wrote

$$\ddot{y_j} =  \left(-\frac{v^2}{\Delta^2}\right)(2y_j - y_{j+1} - y_{j-1}).$$

And here I got stuck.

I don't get if there is some "trick" or meaning for this writing, like something as

$$(y_j - y_{j+1}) = y_j - y_{j+1} - y_{j-1} + y_{j-1}.$$

and then rewriting it, bu I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will write down explicitly the sum, so it is clear.

$$L=\frac{m}{2}\Big(\dot{y}_1+...+\dot{y}_i+...+\dot{y}_n
-\upsilon^2\frac{(y_1-y_2)^2}{\Delta^2}
-\upsilon^2\frac{(y_2-y_3)^2}{\Delta^2}
-...
-\upsilon^2\frac{(y_{i-1}-y_i)^2}{\Delta^2}
-\upsilon^2\frac{(y_i-y_{i+1})^2}{\Delta^2}
-...
-\upsilon^2\frac{(y_n-y_{n+1})^2}{\Delta^2}\Big)$$
So for a certain $i$, there exist two terms in the Lagrangian, containing $y_i$.

Now, the Euler-Lagrange equations yield
$$\frac{d}{dt}\Big(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{y}_i}\Big)=
m\ddot{y}_i\\
\Big(\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_i}\Big)=
-\frac{\upsilon^2}{\Delta^2}\frac{\partial }{\partial y_i}\Big((y_{i-1}-y_i)^2-
(y_{i}-y_{i+1})^2\Big)$$

Comment: That was really clear thank you!! Just a question: is there some reason why you wrote $\Delta$ without the square?

Comment: Simply a typo. Sorry, I will edit now:)

Answer (score 1):

When you take a derivative of the Lagrangian WRT $y_j$ or $\dot{y}_j $ the sum disappears as only a few of the terms in the sum depend on $y_j$ or $\dot{y}_j$ . This is different from what you wrote down as the derivative, where the sum remained.

For the LHS: there is only one term in the Lagrangian that depends on $\dot{y}_j$, namely the one proportional to $\dot{y}_j^2$, and this results in the LHS of the Euler-Lagrange equation being proportional to $\ddot{y}_j$.

For the RHS: there are two terms in the Lagrangian that involve $y_j$, one is proportional to $(y_j - y_{j+1})^2$ and the second is proportional to $(y_j - y_{j-1})^2$. So after taking the derivative WRT $y_j$ you are left with a term proportional to $(y_j - y_{j+1}) + (y_j - y_{j-1}) = (2y_j - y_{j-1} - y_{j-2})$, as your professor wrote.